# failed upgrade to vaadin 24

Tags: vaadin, vaadin24

I've just upgraded to vaadin 24 from vaadin 23.

Now my client application won't load.

I forced a rebuild of the client side components by deleting src/main/dev-bundle and generated.

I also deleted node_modules, package.json and package-lock.json and ran
`mvn vaadin:clean-frontend clean install`
to ensure that I had a nice clean build.

The web server starts without issue and reports

`Vaadin application has been deployed and started to the context path "/".`

When I try to load the client I'm seeing the following errors:

```
Path '/' is not properly resolved due to an error. Resolution had failed on route: '(.*)'
```

```
(index):4 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: Failed to execute 'define' on 'CustomElementRegistry': the name "vaadin-checkbox" has already been used with this registry
    at window.customElements.define (https://xxx/:4:829)
    at https://xxx/VAADIN/dev-bundle/VAADIN/build/generated-flow-imports-7d167742.js:2759:2556
```

And

```
sw.js:1 Uncaught (in promise) bad-precaching-response: bad-precaching-response :: [{"url":"https://xxx/VAADIN/build/component-picker-acd91974.js","status":404}]
    at d._handleInstall (https://xxx/sw.js:1:8531)
    at async d._handle (https://xxx/sw.js:1:7942)
    at async d._getResponse (https://xxx/sw.js:1:7010)
```

The component-picker exists in the build directory and has the correct name.

Edit:
I've found some more pertinent information.

When I look at the network resources being loaded I see:

```
https://xxx/VAADIN/dev-bundle/VAADIN/build/indexhtml-6a220e3b.js
```

Note how VAADIN is in the path twice.

When the component-picker.js load is tried the path is:

```
https://xxx/VAADIN/build/component-picker-acd91974.js
```

This second path looks to be correct, but the first incorrect path is the one that successfully loads.

Edit 2:
I believe that I can see the cause of the error for the CustomElementRegistry.

The generated-flow-imports.js has two CheckBox components.

Both of these are being registered by a call to:

customElements.define(CheckboxElement.is, CheckboxElement);

With CheckboxElement.is returning the same value in both cases.

The first version is:

```
/**
 * @license
 * Copyright (c) 2017 - 2023 Vaadin Ltd.
 * This program is available under Apache License Version 2.0, available at https://vaadin.com/license/
 */
registerStyles$1("vaadin-checkbox", checkboxStyles, {
    moduleId: "vaadin-checkbox-styles"
});
class Checkbox extends CheckboxMixin(ElementMixin$1(ThemableMixin(PolymerElement))) {
    static get is() {
        return "vaadin-checkbox"
    }
    static get template() {
        return html`
      <div class="vaadin-checkbox-container">
        <div part="checkbox" aria-hidden="true"></div>
        <slot name="input"></slot>
        <slot name="label"></slot>
      </div>
      <slot name="tooltip"></slot>
    `
    }
    ready() {
        super.ready(),
        this._tooltipController = new TooltipController(this),
        this.addController(this._tooltipController)
    }
}
customElements.define(Checkbox.is, Checkbox);
```

The second version is:

```js
/**
@license
Copyright (c) 2017 Vaadin Ltd.
This program is available under Apache License Version 2.0, available at https://vaadin.com/license/
*/
class CheckboxElement extends ElementMixin(ControlStateMixin(ThemableMixin(GestureEventListeners(PolymerElement)))) {
    static get template() {
        return html`
    <style>
      :host {
        display: inline-block;
      }

      :host([hidden]) {
        display: none !important;
      }

      label {
        display: inline-flex;
        align-items: baseline;
        outline: none;
      }

      [part="checkbox"] {
        position: relative;
        display: inline-block;
        flex: none;
      }

      input[type="checkbox"] {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        opacity: 0;
        cursor: inherit;
        margin: 0;
      }

      :host([disabled]) {
        -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent;
      }
    </style>

    <label>
      <span part="checkbox">
        <input type="checkbox" checked="{{checked::change}}" disabled\$="[[disabled]]" indeterminate="{{indeterminate::change}}" role="presentation" tabindex="-1">
      </span>

      <span part="label">
        <slot></slot>
      </span>
    </label>
`
    }
    static get is() {
        return "vaadin-checkbox"
    }
    static get version() {
        return "2.5.0"
    }
    static get properties() {
        return {
            checked: {
                type: Boolean,
                value: !1,
                notify: !0,
                observer: "_checkedChanged",
                reflectToAttribute: !0
            },
            indeterminate: {
                type: Boolean,
                notify: !0,
                observer: "_indeterminateChanged",
                reflectToAttribute: !0,
                value: !1
            },
            value: {
                type: String,
                value: "on"
            },
            _nativeCheckbox: {
                type: Object
            }
        }
    }
    constructor() {
        super(),
        this.name
    }
    get name() {
        return this.checked ? this._storedName : ""
    }
    set name(te) {
        this._storedName = te
    }
    ready() {
        super.ready(),
        this.setAttribute("role", "checkbox"),
        this._nativeCheckbox = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('input[type="checkbox"]'),
        this.addEventListener("click", this._handleClick.bind(this)),
        this._addActiveListeners();
        const te = this.getAttribute("name");
        te && (this.name = te),
        this.shadowRoot.querySelector('[part~="label"]').querySelector("slot").addEventListener("slotchange", this._updateLabelAttribute.bind(this)),
        this._updateLabelAttribute()
    }
    _updateLabelAttribute() {
        const te = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('[part~="label"]')
          , ee = te.firstElementChild.assignedNodes();
        this._isAssignedNodesEmpty(ee) ? te.setAttribute("empty", "") : te.removeAttribute("empty")
    }
    _isAssignedNodesEmpty(te) {
        return te.length === 0 || te.length == 1 && te[0].nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE && te[0].textContent.trim() === ""
    }
    _checkedChanged(te) {
        this.indeterminate ? this.setAttribute("aria-checked", "mixed") : this.setAttribute("aria-checked", Boolean(te))
    }
    _indeterminateChanged(te) {
        te ? this.setAttribute("aria-checked", "mixed") : this.setAttribute("aria-checked", this.checked)
    }
    _addActiveListeners() {
        this._addEventListenerToNode(this, "down", te=>{
            this.__interactionsAllowed(te) && this.setAttribute("active", "")
        }
        ),
        this._addEventListenerToNode(this, "up", ()=>this.removeAttribute("active")),
        this.addEventListener("keydown", te=>{
            this.__interactionsAllowed(te) && te.keyCode === 32 && (te.preventDefault(),
            this.setAttribute("active", ""))
        }
        ),
        this.addEventListener("keyup", te=>{
            this.__interactionsAllowed(te) && te.keyCode === 32 && (te.preventDefault(),
            this._toggleChecked(),
            this.removeAttribute("active"),
            this.indeterminate && (this.indeterminate = !1))
        }
        )
    }
    get focusElement() {
        return this.shadowRoot.querySelector("input")
    }
    __interactionsAllowed(te) {
        return !(this.disabled || te.target.localName === "a")
    }
    _handleClick(te) {
        this.__interactionsAllowed(te) && (this.indeterminate ? (this.indeterminate = !1,
        te.preventDefault(),
        this._toggleChecked()) : te.composedPath()[0] !== this._nativeCheckbox && (te.preventDefault(),
        this._toggleChecked()))
    }
    _toggleChecked() {
        this.checked = !this.checked,
        this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("change",{
            composed: !1,
            bubbles: !0
        }))
    }
}
customElements.define(CheckboxElement.is, CheckboxElement);
```

I note that the second version has a version of 2.5.0. This makes me wonder if it is an old version.
My problem is that I can't see any dependency that would be pulling it in.

Comment: Does component-picker use Polymer?